# EditText doesn't get extracted on a tablet

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

I have a layout with an `EditText`, which looks like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp">
    .....

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/some_button">

    <EditText
            android:id="@+id/some_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:hint="@string/some_text_hint"/>
    .....
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

In landscape mode this layout behaves inconsistently. When presented on a phone, `some_text` will be extracted into full-screen when in focus, which is fine. However, with this exact layout, `some_text` won't be extracted if presented on the tablet. I'd like the textbox to be *extracted into full-screen* on the tablet as well.

I'm testing with Nexus 5 phone and Nexus 7 tablet emulator presets, both running Android 4.2.2 (API 17).

**UPD:**
This issue reproduces with any edittext on Samsung Galaxy Tab E device with Android 5.1 and an emulator running Android 5.1 as well.

**UPD2:**
I created a test [empty project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/94h3xharha69kub/MyApplication.zip?dl=0) just to verify that it's indeed a vanilla text box problem. And it is. Now my layout looks literally like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.myapplication.MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="This should be fullscreen"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here's an activity code, just in case:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

And some pictures, just because. This is how the layout is, correctly, rendered on the phone (both emulated and physical):

[image: correct]

And this is what I get on tablets:

[image: incorrect]

Comment: Did you try them on an actual device or are you making that claim based on emulator results?

Comment: your EditText isn't showing up in landscape mode? Am I correct?

Comment: @Shark I got bug reports from end users with physical devices and managed to reproduce the same behavior with an emulator.

Comment: @VladimirKulyk, the textbox is there, it can get focus and receive input just fine, but it doesn't get extracted.

Comment: Are you omitting other views from your snippet? Likely the screen is simply too small to squeeze them all in. Either make the height of some views dynamic, or make the whole or parts scrollable.

Comment: @PaulLammertsma this shouldn't matter. Textbox receives focus, device is in landscape mode, it has to be extracted and become fullscreen. It happens on phone devices and emaulator, doesn't happen on tablet devices and emulators. I want to know why and how to work around it.

Comment: @Dmitriy Based on the description of the issue and the view hierarchy that you've provided, I wouldn't be so quick to dismiss it. I'd start by reproducing the problem and including a screenshot here, in the meantime providing the rest of your layout in your snippet above.

Comment: Sure thing, @PaulLammertsma. I updated the post with screenshots and provided a blank project, created by Android Studio, where the issue reproduces.

Comment: @Dmitriy Great, thanks! What you're seeing on smaller devices is something called "extracted text UI". Unfortunately, there's no way to invoke it manually; to my knowledge, you can only disable it by providing the `imeOption` `EditorInfo.IME_FLAG_NO_EXTRACT_UI`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some research and digging through Android sources I found out that extracting text edits is an input method (keyboard) responsibility. There is no way to force the keyboard to extract your views.

My HTC devices have HTC keyboard set by default, and it does extract text edits unless `IME_FLAG_NO_EXTRACT_UI` is set. My customers have Samsung tablets, which have Samsung keyboard set by default, which doesn't extract text edits on Samsung tablets. Emulators have Google keyboard set by default, and it extracts text edits whenever it feels like it (does extract on 5" emulator, doesn't extract on 5" device).

One of the solutions was to find or implement a keyboard replacement, which extracts text edits in landscape mode, and then recommend users to install it. And that's a crappy solution, because nobody's going to do that.

So I ended up just making sure that my UI doesn't rely on text edits being extracted. In my case my form contained textboxes inside a scrollable element. By default, when textbox is focused, android makes a decision between two options:

1. Pan the view and move the textbox into visible position. This behavior is called `adjustPan`
2. Reduce the available height of the view, shrinking everything as a result. This behavior is called `adjustResize`.

If you don't mess with options, then Android chooses 2nd option if there's at least one scrollable element present in the view. Otherwise it pans the view. You can influence this decision by assigning `android:windowSoftInputMode` attribute to your activity in the manifest with either `adjustPan` or `adjustResize` value.

In the end I've chosen `adjustPan` behavior and re-arranged elements on the view slightly to make sure that panned view made sense and didn't look weird.